# Streaming videos with h.263/mpeg-4 encoding over rtsp

Tags: video-streaming, rtsp

I am working on product where in I need to stream videos to mobile devices, most of which are feature phones. The most widely supported video/audio codecs on these devices is mpeg-4/aac and  h.263/aar. So I am looking for a solution to be able to stream videos with these encoding formats over rtsp.

So far, I have looked at Adobe Flash Media Server and Wowza. FMS doesn't support rtsp and Wowza only seems to work with h.264 encoded videos.

If anyone can point me to a solution to stream h.263/mpeg-4 encoded videos over rtsp, I would  really appreciate the help.

Comment: Also take a look at `Erlyvideo` & `Evostream`.

Answer (score 0):

[Darwin streaming server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_Streaming_Server) seems to do the job. The only catch is that for streaming videos, files need to be hinted first. That can be easily achieved using [MP4Box](http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/).